# Single process run with multiple user id

Tags: bash, shell, unix, proc

I have a shell script (Bash) which in turn calls `proc` binary. It is scheduled using a `scheduled` at a specific time with a user id as `c62feed`. We have other backend system used ids like `reco` and `accreter`. I have  recently noticed that this script was run using `c62feed` but the output file created by this script was partly with `c62feed` and other half with `reco`. And all these files have been created at the same time, so there is no chance of someone manually using `reco` and running this process. I have shown below sample output files details:

```
-rw-rw-rw-   1 reco     162399477 May  8 12:03 MHS_PA
-rw-rw-rw-   1 reco     32012461 May  8 12:03 MHS_NJ
-rw-rw-rw-   1 c62feed  21707404 May  8 12:03 MHS_PC
-rw-rw-rw-   1 reco     27782603 May  8 12:03 MHS_MB
-rw-rw-rw-   1 c62feed  71198525 May  8 12:03 MHS_PW
```

You can see that files have been created using both possible. I would like to know if it's possible. I checked this script and `proc`. Nowhere we use `reco` id.

I would like to know is it possible at a time user ids will be switched at a time?

Comment: Assuming the MHS_C is a problem file, is the data inside all from one source? Either way, it seems most likely that the c62feed hadn't finished, when the reco process started, and that the c62feed wrote the last lines into your file. Solution? Numerous ways, but you'll have to make sure one run is done processing all files, before the other run starts up. To prove that, change the timing to 2-3x longer than the current delays. Good luck.

Comment: This script was run by c62feed from begining.Not sure how reco had come last time in between when the process was run.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if the files MHS_PA, MHS_NJ and MHS_MB had been created previously by `reco`, when the program is run by `c62feed`, unless the program first removes the file with `unlink()`, the files will be left owned by `reco`.  The 666 permissions are problematic; public write permission is always problematic.  But it does mean that your program can write to files that are not owned by `c62feed`.

You should carefully remove the files (or move them, or move the directory), and try again.  I expect you'll find that the newly created files are consistently owned by `c62feed`.

There aren't many ways for a process that is not run with `root` privileges to change UID while it is running. One exception is if the program has the SUID (set user ID) bit set to one user and it is run by another.

What are the permissions on the `proc` program?

Comment: 666 was given yesterday for these files since it threw error when i tried to run it with c62feed and could nt write MHS_PA, MHS_NJ etc as it was owned by reco. Earlier these file were having 644 permissions, and user name was c62feed - MHS_PC , MHS_PW and reco - MHS_PA, MHS_NJ and MHS_MB and it all happened on same day April 15th at 2:14 pm. when files had 644 permission, reco should not have written this files before.So I wonder, if i change the file permission back to 644, same situation will happen again where reco will write the files which should not happen.Proc file permission is 854.

Comment: As I said, I think you need to put the current behaviour down to something aberrant happened.  You should clean up the files with the incorrect owner (as `c62feed`, copy the file to file.new, move the file to file.old, move file.new to file, remove file.old) and then monitor what happens on the next cycle.  I'd be very inclined to put the permissions back to 644 on the files, and 755 on the directory, and then see what fails as `reco`.